# React-native-firebase phone authentication

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am currently using react-native-firebase/auth for phone authentication
Ive linked everything and followed all the steps but i get this error when providing the confirmation code and running the confirm function provided by the module.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'native' of undefined
at confirm (ConfirmationResult.js:25)
```

this is the code that throws the error

```
    const { confirm } = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(`+1 ${number}`)
    confirm('123456')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you're getting the result value in const. The value returned is not a function.

You can use this code

```js
signIn = async () => {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
  const confirm = await firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  console.log(confirm);

}
```

Comment: Yes this ended up working. I was following their updated documentation which seems to be wrong. Thanks!